# Proving the mean value theorem with non-standard definitions of continuity and the derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, proof-writing

Consider the following definitions of continuity and the derivative

---

> A function is said to be continuous at $x = c$ if and only if the function $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ where $g(x) = (x, f(x))$ satisfies the usual continuity definition at $x = c$, that is
>
> $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \; \delta_\varepsilon > 0 : |x - c| < \delta_\varepsilon \implies |g(x) - g(c)| < \varepsilon$
>
> with respect to the standard topology of $\mathbb R^2$.

---

> A function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is said to be have a derivative $a$ at $x = c$, denoted $f'(c) = a$, if and only if there exists an unique  affine function $g(x) = ax + b$ and a real number $\delta > 0$ such that the equation
>
> $ax + b = f(x)$ has an unique solution whenever $|x-c| < \delta$
>
> Moreover, we require that the sign of $h(x) = ax + b - f(x)$ must be the same in $(c-\delta, c)$ and $(c, c+\delta)$.

---

Under these alternative and non-standard definitions, is the mean value theorem true? That is,

> $\begin{cases}f \text{ is continuous at all } x \text{ in } [a, b] \\ \exists f'(x) \text{ for all } x \text{ in } (a, b) \end{cases} \implies \exists \xi \in (a, b) : f'(\xi) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$

Comment: You should be aware that your derivative is not uniquely defined. For example when $f(x) = |x|$, then $f'(0)$ is equal to every number in $(-1, 1)$ (and the derivative is undefined everywhere else!).

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you for pointing this out, and we can fix this by requiring $f$ is unique. I also added the requirement that the difference $ax + b - f(x)$ must have the same sign in the intervals $(c-\delta, c)$ and $(c, c+\delta)$.